# Function always returns the value from the first condition

Tags: php, scope, return

Total newbie to PHP with problem. Here is function that calculate if value is between ex. 0,00 and 1.500,00 then discount number is 8

```
function wpsc_cart_discount_number(){
    global $wpsc_cart;
    if   ($total >= 0000 && $total < 1500) {
        return $discount->wpsc_cart_discount_number = '8';
    }   if ($total >= 1500 && $total < 3000) {
        return $discount->wpsc_cart_discount_number = '11';
    }   if ($total >= 3000 && $total < 7000) {
        return $discount->wpsc_cart_discount_number = '13';
    }  if ($total >= 7000 && $total < 10000) {
        return $discount->wpsc_cart_discount_number = '16';
    }  if ($total >= 10000) {
        return $discount->wpsc_cart_discount_number = '18';
    }
}
```

When I call this function it keep returning only value of "8" and not others. What is wrong here?

Comment: Just for clarity for everyone on the forum it may be useful if you contained more info in the title and tags of your question, such as "PHP: Multiple return values in function issue" or something :)

Comment: you might want to use elseif in this statement instead of 6 if statements :P but I doubt thats the solution to the problem

Comment: Tried it but it keeps returning the same value as above "8"

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact, that you do not have a local `$total` variable in your function, it is undefined. By the flexible error handling of PHP, this would be only a notice, not an error. An undefined value is treated as `0` when compared to integers, therefore the first condition will be always be true.

Comment: Total is not predefined it is calulated during adding to cart process, wpsc_cart_discount_number i use one other php form that create pdf invoice and no matter if total in my cart is 700€ or 7000€ it keeps showing on pdf discount number 8. Here is the part from pdf generator invoice `$params[]= array('unique_name'=>'$params[]= array('unique_name'=>'cart_total','value'=>wpsc_cart_total());
   $params[]= array('unique_name'=>'popust','value'=>wpsc_cart_popust());`

Comment: `$total` is a local variable and I do not see an assignment to it in the above function.

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a look at it I'm guessing you don't have $total being defined. Can you put some debug code and see if you $total has a value?

Or post more of the code and where $total is being defined.